# How do I save process values saved in a .txt file to 4 different arrays in c

Tags: c, memory-management, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, virtual-memory

Given processes.txt with the following information

```
0 4 96 30
3 2 32 40
5 1 100 20
20 3 4 30
```

How do I save each row of the file as elements of 4 different arrays in c?
i.e.

```
int arr1 = [0,4,96,30]
int arr2 = [3,2,32,40]
int arr3 = [5,1,100,20]
int arr[4] = [20,3,4,30]
```

Here is my code where I have loaded the .txt file but do not know how to store the values in an integer array.  My code produces garbage values.

How can I write the program?

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
     FILE *fp;
     char *filename;
     char ch;

      // Check if a filename has been specified in the command
      if (argc < 2)
       {
            printf("Missing Filename\n");
            return(1);
       }
       else
      {
            filename = argv[1];
            printf("Filename : %s\n", filename);
       }

       // Open file in read-only mode
       fp = fopen(filename,"r");

       // If file opened successfully, then print the contents
       if ( fp )
          {
            printf("File contents:\n");
            while ( (ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF )
               {
                    printf("%c",ch);
               }

           }
       else
          {
             printf("Failed to open the file\n");
            }
       // Saving the contents of the file in a Number Array
            int numberArray[16];
            int i;

        for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &numberArray[i]);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            printf("Number is: %d\n\n", numberArray[i]);
        }


    return(0);
    }
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: This question needs to be narrowed down somewhat. If you are stuck on writing/accessing array elements, then the material about scheduler emulation can be removed. Readers are happy to help with small, focussed problems, but not do the whole project for you.

Comment: Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) then more [about C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). Write your program using some source code editor like [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) or many others. StackOverflow is *not* a *do-my-homework* website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reset the pointer `fp` to start of file. Because the `while` loop: `while ( (ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF )`, the pointer `fp` is at the end of file.

```
int numberArray[16];
int i;
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

The `for` loop for `fscanf` should be replaced by `while` loop:

```
        int numberArray[16];
        int i = 0;
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &numberArray[i]) == 1 && i < 16)
        {
            i++;
        }
        // Then when you print the value from 0 to i
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            printf("Number is: %d\n\n", numberArray[j]);
        }
```

Do not forget to close the file when you do not need to use it:

```
fclose(fp);
```

Now, if you want to separate the `numberArray` to 4 array `arr1`, `arr2`, `arr3` and `arr4`.  You can assign first 4 elements of `numberArray` (form `0` to `3`) to `arr1`, then the next 4 elements (from `4` to `7`) to `arr2` and so on.